# SQL Server 2012 (SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU) Installer doesn't open/do anything

Tags: windows-8, installation, sql-server, sql-server-express

I just downloaded SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU (multiple times, to verify it worked as expected), which is supposed to be SQL Server Express 2012 with Tools, from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPWT/enus/default.aspx).

It appears to be a file with no extension, just `SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU`. I have enabled showing file extensions for all types in explorer, so it can't be hiding the extension (I assume).

I have tried adding exe, iso, rar, and zip extensions, but I can't open, run, mount, or execute the file. What kind of file is this supposed to be? Does anyone know how to open/install this? Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am testing downloading it right now in Windows 7 and Windows 8.

On Windows 7 and with Chrome and it shows the file with a `.exe` extension. 
[image: chrome]

And on Windows 8 with IE it prompts to save as type *.exe
[image]

Once downloaded you should be able to just double-click to run it. You may also have to right-click and select `Run as Administrator` to get it to install. You should not have to rename it or add an extension.

I will update this answer when it finishes downloading.

Comment: it doesnt work for me from [link](https://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPWT/enus/default.aspx), but it works from [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062), but now I am having install issue due this idiotic replacement pc i got while my pc is in maintenance. anyway, thanks for your effort, i appreciate them :) If you happen to know anything about MySQL, which I am trying as a replacement for MS SQL Server, you can post here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993089/start-mysql-server-as-a-service-win-8) ;) Thanks for your efforts! :)